# jQuery not registering change function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 / C# 4.0 / MVC 3 / Razor / jQuery 1.5.1 / Google Chrome 21.0.1180.83 m / Windows 7 Enterprise

Here is my exact code with non-salient things (well what I think is non-salient) commented out.

Basically I'm creating an `<input />` element and am trying to bind a change event to it if the user changes its value, but the event doesn't seem to be binding.  When I look at the elements in Google Chrome (Ctrl + Shift + J), I do not see anything under "Event Listeners."

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
// ...

    $('#StoredProcedureName').change(function () {
        // ...

        var parameters = $('#parameters');  // <table id="parameters"></table>

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action(/* */)', {
            // ...
        }, function (data) {
            parameters.empty();
            // ...
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                // ...
                parameters.
                    append($('<tr />').
                        // ... Other <td /> elements
                        append($('<td />').
                            append($('<input />').
                                // ...
                                change(function () {
                                    alert("here2"); // This alert isn't happening.
                                }).
                                addClass('testClass'). // This class is showing up though.
                                // ...
                            )
                        )
                    );
            });

            // ...
        });
    });

    // ...
});

</script>
```

When I make a test MVC website and do this, it seems to work.  This is so puzzling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#a").append(
                $("<input />").change(function () {
                    alert("here1");
                }).attr('value', 'text')
            );
            $("#b").change(function () {
                alert("here2");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">
    </div>
    <input id="b" />
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me why my first alert isn't being executed, in spite of the `<input />` element showing up, with the proper class?

**Edit:**

The table is being created, along with the input element:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome inspector]

Comment: This definitely sounds like the jQuery library isn't loading properly - Are you sure your site is running from the root of the webserver (not `/MyApp/`) ? If not, your jQuery path will be incorrect. Look in the "Net" tab and see if you can see the library loading correctly

Comment: Could you link your orginal html page as well? I'm not seeing a textbox with id StoredProcedureName, maybe it's called SPNAME or you made a typo?

Comment: @Basic: The jQuery library is generating the `<td>`.  I do not see errors from `$` being invalid in the console.  I'm not sure what you mean by the net tab - in Chrome?

Comment: @Kristof: Later in my page I have: `<div>
    Select a Stored Procedure: 
    @Html.DropDownList("StoredProcedureName", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
</div>`.  It's there.  The table is being built.  `<tr />` and `<td />` elements are appearing.  The `<input />` element is there.  It's just when I change it, the alert isn't happening.  And there isn't an event in the Event Listeners when I inspect the generated element in Chrome.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared The Ctrl-Shift-J panel has a "Network" tab which shows all resources downloaded for that page. That said, I hadn't realised some jQuery was working so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: You might have done this already, but just in case.  There are no javascript errors reported right?  All bets are off if there are errors on the page.

Comment: @JasonDam There were no errors like that.  I figured it out, though -- my answer explains briefly if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to edit this with an explanation.  But basically inside my code I was sorting the table elements like so:

```
var options = parameters.children();
options.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    else if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    else return 0
});
parameters.empty().append(options);
```

Removing this (I'm not sure why I had it) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it without the table elements?

I am just wondering about how you are doing this:

```
append($('<tr />')
```

I would expect that to be a closed table row, and likewise with the

```
append($('<td />')
```

Have a look at this example for table building

[Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm building my table similar to the highest answer on that question, except I am not doing `.find('tbody')`.  I can try that.  Hang on.

Comment: What I was getting at is that youi are using closed table tags <tr/> rather than <tr><td>...<input />...</tr></tr>.  So unless I have missed something I am not sure your input will actually be in the intended place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- I thought `<div />` in a selector is the same as `<div></div>` ?  See the image I uploaded in my question -- it shows the input element appearing.  So I think it's in the intended place, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yeah, just seen your image, so I think the structure looks ok, its puzzling.

Comment: Sorry, I added something I then realised was irrelevant and couldn't find a way to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

personally i would try to add a class to the input field and use jqueries Live() function in stead of normal binding.
You can bind the onclick to all input's with class foo.

[Info about Live here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

 if you don't like the live could you try not doing the .change binding immediatly but call an extra jquery selector on it's id like you did in your working example?